# Matrix decomposition with contraints

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

I am planning to decompose the Hermitian matrix X (which is function of r, $\theta$) which is a square matrix as $X=ABA^H$.

Let us assume size of A is NxL where L is the no. of Eigen vectors which is function of (m,n). If we decompose X into L Eigen vectors and every $i^{th}$ Eigen vector A(:,i) is very arbitrary (EVD).

I would like to put a constraint on A such that; $A(:,i)=\phi_{m,n}(r)e^{im\theta}$.

I would like to calculate $\phi_{m,n}$ (L=m $\times$ n) vectors).

Kindly let me know if this doesn't make sense. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is $X$ symmetric? Also, are these matrices real?  If not, should $T$ really be a conjugate-transpose?

Comment: Yes X is symmetric!

Comment: The fact that $X$ is symmetric should be included in your question

Comment: Sorry I changed it to conjugate transpose. Matrices are complex.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what it means to "decompose X into L modes".  What's a "mode"? I assume $A(:,i)$ is Matlab notation for the $i$th column.

Comment: yes! Sorry I m being bad here .... yes yes it is Matlab notation. What I mean is L eigen vectors.

Comment: Okay, it's making a lot more sense now.  Another question: I see that $A(:,i)$ is a vector, but how is $\phi_{m,n}(r)^{im \theta}$ a vector?  If the latter is not a vector, how do I interpret the equation
$$
A(:,i) = \phi_{m,n}(r)^{im \theta}?
$$

Comment: $\phi_{m,n}(r)e^{im\theta}$ is a vector. Every combinations of $r,\theta$ give elements of the vector $A(:,i)$. Every combinations of $m,n$ gives different Eigen vectors L. I hope this is clear.

Comment: Okay, I understand that $A$ has a column for every pair $m,n$ with $1 \leq m \leq M$ and $1 \leq n \leq N$ (although you're not differentiating between $m$ and $M$ for some reason), but how many rows does $A$ have?  The entries of each column are supposed to be given by "combinations of $r$ and $\theta$"; I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Really sorry for the confusion .... I will try to formulate differently ... Basically I am expressing a function as 

$u(r,\theta)=\sum_m\sum_n A_{mn}\phi_{mn}(r)e^{im\theta}$,

I only know matrix C=[uu^*], and I would like to calculate the functions $\phi_{mn}$ and coefficients $AA^*$ .... by using POD or EVM approach or any other approaches. This is my whole problem... thanks a lot for your time ....